# Sound not working on Huawei Matebook D15 AMD

Tags: sound, 22.04, huawei

When I go in the sound settings the only available option is Dummy Output. I looked everywhere for help, the only thing that had effect was adding the line
`options snd-hda-intel model=generic`
at the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf that made appear the option for HDMI in the sound settings.
The sound is working on bluetooth earphones.

I also tried installing the most recent kernel up to the 5.18 but nothing changed.

I have installed Xubuntu 22.04 with dual boot with windows. Everything works fine in Windows.

Comment: Have same issue and still looking for a solution